# Trying to add folder through Env DTE ProjectItem.AddFolder but getting folder already exists

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsix, envdte

I'm generating some code using T4 templates and adding them to a project using EnvDTE

In order to add a file into the correct folder of the project, I'm "recursively" searching the project items for the folder I want to add the new item to. If it doesn't exist, I want to add it.

```
            var directories = resultPath.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).ToList();
            var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(project.FullName);
            ProjectItem item = null;
            foreach (var dir in directories)
            {
                path = Path.Combine(path, dir);
                item = FindProjectItem(path, dir, item == null ? project.ProjectItems : item.ProjectItems);
            }

            if (item != null)
            {
                item.ProjectItems.AddFromFileCopy(workingFullPath);
            }
```

```
        private ProjectItem FindProjectItem(string fullPath, string directory, ProjectItems items)
        {
            foreach (ProjectItem item in items)
            {
                if (string.Equals(item.Name, directory, System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    return item;
                }
            }

            if (Directory.Exists(fullPath))
            {
                Directory.Delete(fullPath);
            }

            return items.AddFolder(directory);

        }
```

Previous tests have generated the folders/files I need, which I have then deleted through visual studio.

When subsequent tests are run, despite not locating the folder as a project item, the code breaks when trying to add the new folder with the error "Folder already exists".

Comment: Did you checked that folder is there or not? even if you deleted that folder through VS but still that folder would be there. Please check that folder on your machine and delete it from there. You can do that by opening your solution folder in file explorer

Comment: The folder is still there, which is what is frustrating here, as how can I ensure that this has been deleted properly (and if not, delete it myself) without having to find the folder manually ?